# Overriding default PHP error messages with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

When adding more than 20 attachments to a contact form file input; PHP returns the following message:

```
Warning: Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded in Unknown on line 0
```

I can't replace this message with my own because it happens before my PHP script executes. Although If I get the returned warning and parse it with JavaScript, I can replace it with my own simpler warning message. Is there such a library that does this sort of thing with many warning and error messages that can't be changed with PHP?

Comment: Have you tried to locate the file that contains the maximum n umber of files to upload? There should be text that can you can edit or add to whatever is in there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the `max_file_uploads` setting in php.ini, there is no way around it, if you want to use the code you have.

Or do something different, like submit the files in separate requests using AJAX.

Comment: Hi, I submit the form with AJAX and can get the returned message. changing the max_file_uploads is not the solution I'm looking for. I want to manage the warning message.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of styling the error message generated by PHP, you want to prevent it ever getting to that point. You need to implement validation before your AJAX gets submitted, so if your server only allows `x` file uploads at one time do:

Jquery:

```
if($("input:file")[0].files.length>x) {
    // perform your ajax request
} else {
    // show your error message
}
```

Comment: Good Idea. However there are other warnings that can't be validated this way. For example the max file upload size warning.